# Problem with changing schedule_id in table msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a script that changes the schedule on a job, but the problem is that even if it looks right when looking in SQL Server agent it still operates like the old schedule.

This is how I change the schedule;

```
update msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
set schedule_id = 25
where job_id = '1256497D-2960-469A-AE91-F4E750AD5AC7'
```

I've tried using sp_update_job to disable and then enable it again but that wont help.

Is there another way to change a jobs schedule?
Running SQL2014.

/Tomas

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sp_detach_schedule and sp_attach_schedule to remove and add a schedule.

## sp_attach_schedule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-schedule-transact-sql

## sp_detach_schedule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-schedule-transact-sql